# How can I set the props type in HOC in react-typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, higher-order-components

I have a simple withAuth HOC. I am trying to define the type for props.

```
const withAuth = (Component: typeof React.Component) => (role: string) => {
  return (props) => {
    const { data, loading } = useGetUser();
    if (loading) {
      return <p>Loading...</p>;
    }

    if (!data) {
      return <Redirect ssr to="/api/v1/login" />;
    } else {
      if (role && !isAuthorized(data, role)) {
        return <Redirect ssr to="/api/v1/login" />;
      }

      return <Component user={data} loading={loading} {...props} />;
    }
  };
};
```

I tried this:

```
React.Component<T>
```

Then passing the `T` to `props:T` i am getting 2 warnings.

```
  Component: typeof React.Component<T> // Parameter '(Missing)' implicitly has an 'any' type.

 props:T // Cannot find name 'T'
```

Comment: Try `const withAuth = (Component: React.ReactNode)`?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'

type Props = {
  name: string
}

const A: FC<Props> = () => <div></div>


const withAuth = <P extends object>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) => (role: string) => {
  return (props: P) => {
    return <Component {...props} />;
  }
};

const result1 = withAuth(A)('hello')({ label: 'hello' }) // error
const result2 = withAuth(A)('hello')({ name: 'hello' }) // ok
```